# Classic ASP - Implementing SMTP authentication in sending emails via CDONTS

Tags: email, asp-classic, smtp, cdonts

Below is an already working code in classic ASP to send an email. Can we implement SMTP authentication to this code?

I have implemented using CDO, but would like to know if we can implement SMTP authentication for CDONTS. Please see my code below:

```
Set objCDO = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
objCDO.to = "testrecipient@domain.com"
objCDO.From = "testsender@domain.com" 'CustEmail

objCDO.Subject = "Test Subject"
objCDO.BodyFormat = 0 
objCDO.MailFormat = 0 
objCDO.Body = "This is a test message"
objCDO.Importance = 0 'High importance!
objCDO.Send 'Send off the email!
'Cleanup
Set objCDO = Nothing
ReplySent="Email sent!"
Response.write(ReplySent)
Response.End
```

Comment: CDONTS was dropped from Windows Server 2003, so any server on which you find it is going to be pretty old, unless you've chosen to install it yourself.  As far as I know CDONTS doesn't allow you to use a remote server, you can only use the one on the local machine (if it exists), so there's no equivalent of the CDO config section

Comment: @John, Thank you for the confirmation. How can we check if an SMTP server exists in the local machine?

Comment: This might help https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-configure-iis-for-relay-with-office-365-eb57abd2-3859-4e79-b721-2ed1f0f579c9

Comment: @John, Thank you, I will take a look at this. Sorry for the late reply. :)